# What is the best way to add / remove the table row via AJAX after adding data in database

Tags: jquery, ajax

Quite often i need to `add/delete/update` the item in database via Jquery POST.
Now the next step is to either dynamically add row again via AJAX to show that this row was added or remove the row if it was deleted.

I want to know which method is best and used by companies.

The other solution i think is to update the whole List with jquery so that i don't need to program separate function for edit/add/delete

So how should i go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading whole list is very inefficient. It slows user too.
Server can respond informatically about the database action. So if the operation succeeds, server can respond for example:

```
{'response': 'OK'}
```

and if operation fails, server can respond something like:

```
{'response': 'FAILED', 'message': 'Problems with database connection'}
```

You can then update the affected list row, depending on the response, in the ajax callback function.

Comment: THe problem is not that , in order to insert row i have to perform too much work on adding classes , ids tr td

Comment: Well, that "too much work" is still less work, then reloading the whole list (i mean, computer work). 
You should make a function that will add/edit row for you based on data in parameter.
You can inspire for example in DOJO toolkit's - Grid